# Не выходит обновить адаптер. RecyclerView

Tags: android, adapter, recyclerview

Есть код фрагмента, где для `recyclerView` ставлю свой адаптер `rvDownloadAdapter`
Если я заполню массив до инициализации адаптера то элементы отображаются в `recyclerView` работает. Как к примеру я вношу изначально один элемент в массив.

Дальше я вызываю AsyncTask где получаю с бд данные и в классе `PHPFunction` заполняю массив и возвращаю его. Но когда в `onPostExecute` обновляю адаптер то он не обновляется, думал изначально что пустой массив, но потом я вывожу в лог размер массива и мне выдает что размер равен четырем т.е. массив не пустой.

Вот код фрагмента:

```
public class DownloadCentrFragment extends Fragment
{
    Context context;
    Resources resources;

    TabLayout tabLayout;
    ViewPager viewPager;

    List<View> pages = new ArrayList<View>();
    List<String> titles = new ArrayList<String>();

    ArrayList<itemGetServerList> itemGetServerInfos = new ArrayList<itemGetServerList>();

    RVDownloadAdapter rvDownloadAdapter = null;

    public DownloadCentrFragment()
    {}

    public DownloadCentrFragment setInstance()
    {
        DownloadCentrFragment fragment = new DownloadCentrFragment();
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_download_centr, container, false);

        context = this.getActivity().getApplicationContext();
        resources = this.getActivity().getResources();

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewPager);

        titles.add(resources.getString(R.string.text_UsersList));
        titles.add(resources.getString(R.string.text_YouList));

        View v1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home_download_centr, null);

        EditText SearchText = (EditText) v1.findViewById(R.id.SearchText);
        ImageView Search = (ImageView) v1.findViewById(R.id.Search);
        ImageView Filtr = (ImageView) v1.findViewById(R.id.Filtr);
        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) v1.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(view.getContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(llm);

        itemGetServerInfos.add(new itemGetServerList("Таблица умножения на два", 228, 5, "7-9", "Таблица на два от тред до семи", "","","arif","", null));

        rvDownloadAdapter = new RVDownloadAdapter(itemGetServerInfos, view.getContext());

        recyclerView.setAdapter(new AlphaInAnimationAdapter(rvDownloadAdapter));

        ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(view.getContext(),pages,titles);

        pages.add(v1);

        viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        new LoadInfoTask().execute();

        return view;
    }


    class LoadInfoTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
    {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
        {
            itemGetServerInfos = new PHPFunction(resources, context).getInList(0,30);

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
        {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            rvDownloadAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            Log.d("myLog", itemGetServerInfos.size() + " sizes");
        }
    }
}
```

rvDownloadAdapter

```
public class RVDownloadAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RVDownloadAdapter.ViewHolder>
    {
        ArrayList<itemGetServerList> itemGetServerInfo = new ArrayList<itemGetServerList>();
        Context context;

        public RVDownloadAdapter (ArrayList<itemGetServerList> itemGetServerInfoLoad, Context context)
        {
            this.itemGetServerInfo = itemGetServerInfoLoad;
            this.context = context;
        }

        public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
        {
            View view;
            CardView cardView;
            ImageView icon;
            TextView NameList;
            TextView Des;
            TextView Rating;
            TextView Age;

            ViewHolder(View itemView)
            {
                super(itemView);
                cardView = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_view);
                icon = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
                NameList = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.nameList);
                Des = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.des);
                Rating = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rating);
                Age = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.age);
                view = itemView;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
        {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_download_card, parent, false);
            ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);

            return vh;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position)
        {
            final itemGetServerList infoData = itemGetServerInfo.get(position);

            holder.NameList.setText(itemGetServerInfo.get(position).NameList);
            holder.Des.setText(itemGetServerInfo.get(position).Des);
            holder.Rating.setText(itemGetServerInfo.get(position).Rating + "");
            holder.Age.setText(itemGetServerInfo.get(position).Age);

            switch (itemGetServerInfo.get(position).Tag)
            {
                case "orph":
                    holder.icon.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_orphographic));
                    break;
                case "arif":
                    holder.icon.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_arithmetic));
                    break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView)
        {
            super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount()
        {
            return itemGetServerInfo.size();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Что за класс `rvDownloadAdapter`? Вы назначили в качестве адаптера  класс `AlphaInAnimationAdapter`, именно уму и нужно делать `notifyDataSetChanged()`, чтобы список обновился.  В качестве данных для адаптера `AlphaInAnimationAdapter` назначенного  `RecyclerView` вы используете другой адаптер или я вообще не понимаю вашу логику.

Comment: Покажите AlphaInAnimationAdapter и RVDownloadAdapter

Comment: @pavlofff 'AlphaInAnimationAdapter' это компонент из библиотеки https://github.com/wasabeef/recyclerview-animators для анимации, а 'rvDownloadAdapter' это обычный адаптер для 'recyclerview'

Comment: @pavlofff обновил

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei 'AlphaInAnimationAdapter' это компонент из библиотеки github.com/wasabeef/recyclerview-animators для анимации, а 'rvDownloadAdapter' это обычный адаптер для 'recyclerview' , обновил.

Comment: ну а вы читали в инструкции  к библиотеке, которую используете [раздел *step 2*](https://github.com/wasabeef/recyclerview-animators#step-2) , особенно выделенное примечание?

Comment: @pavlofff и так тоже пробовал, если делать в основном потоке то все работает.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Не знаю, решит ли этот пример именно вашу проблему, так как вы используете в адаптере стороннюю библиотеку, в описании которой сказано, что метод `notifyDataSetChanged()` не работает при использовании анимации.

В адаптере `RecyclerView` действительно есть какая то проблема и метод `notifyDataSetChanged()` не всегда работает корректно, сам разработчик рекомендует использовать этот метод в крайних случаях, а в замен предлагает целый набор: `notifyItemChanged()`, `notifyItemInserted()`, `notifyItemRemoved()`, `notifyItemRangeChanged()`, `notifyItemRangeInserted()`, `notifyItemRangeRemoved()` , что не всегда решает требуемые задачи и опальный метод порой нужен, как никогда.

В общем я использовал такой "костыль" и он исправно работал - принудительно передавать в адаптер изменившиеся данные и только затем обновлять список. Для этого в адаптере делаем простой метод (здесь - `dataChanged()`), обновляющий данные, а затем и сам список.

Приведу свое решение на основе кода вашего адаптера, раз уж он имеется:

```
public class RVDownloadAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RVDownloadAdapter.ViewHolder> {
        ArrayList<itemGetServerList> itemGetServerInfo;
        Context context;

        public RVDownloadAdapter (ArrayList<itemGetServerList> itemGetServerInfoLoad, Context context) {
            itemGetServerInfo = itemGetServerInfoLoad;
            this.context = context;
        }

        ..... // прочий код адаптера

        public dataChanged( ArrayList<itemGetServerList> itemGetServerInfoLoad){

             itemGetServerInfo = itemGetServerInfoLoad;
             notifyDataSetChanged();
         }
}
```

когда данные необходимо обновить, используется данный метод, в который непосредственно и передаются новые данные:

```
rvDownloadAdapter.dataChanged(itemGetServerInfos);
```