# Android не работает notifyDataSetChanged в RecyclerView

Tags: android, recyclerview, adapter, android-sqlite

Есть база данных с рецептами в 6 таблицах. При вызове `Navigatioт Drawer` закрывается,но `notifyDataSetChanged` данные не обновляет. Остаются те данные, которые вызваны `вinitRecyclerView`

Вот код Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    private DrawerLayout drawer;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    RecipeAdapter adapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        initRecyclerView();
        initDrawerNavigation();

    }private void initRecyclerView() {
        recyclerView= (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_list);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        adapter=new RecipeAdapter(this);
        adapter.setRecipes(Tables.DRINKS.getTableName());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    private void initDrawerNavigation() {
        Toolbar toolbar=(Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
        drawer=(DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle=new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,drawer,toolbar, R.string.drawer_open,R.string.drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        String table = Tables.MEAT.getTableName();
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.action_open_cakes:
                 table =Tables.CAKES.getTableName();
                 break;
            case R.id.action_open_drinks:
                table = Tables.DRINKS.getTableName();
                break;
            case R.id.action_open_fishes:
                table = Tables.FISHES.getTableName();
                break;
            case R.id.action_open_meat:
                table=Tables.MEAT.getTableName();
                break;
            case R.id.action_open_salads:
                table = Tables.SALADS.getTableName();
                break;
            case R.id.action_open_soups:
                table =Tables.SOUPS.getTableName();
                break;
        }

        drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        ((RecipeAdapter)recyclerView.getAdapter()).setRecipes(table);
        recyclerView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed(){
        drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)){
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }
        else{
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
```

Это код адаптера

```
public class RecipeAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecipeAdapter.RecipeHolder>{
    Context context;
    List<Recipe> recipes;
    public RecipeAdapter(Context context){
     this.context=context;
     Log.i("adapter","adapter is created");

}
public void setRecipes(String table) {
    RecipeLab recipeLab=RecipeLab.getInstance(context);
    recipes=recipeLab.getRecipes(table);
}

@Override
public RecipeHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v= LayoutInflater.from(context.getApplicationContext()).inflate(R.layout.recipe_item,parent,false);
    Log.i("recyclerView","RecipeHolder is created");
    return new RecipeHolder(v);

}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecipeHolder holder, int position) {
    Log.i("recyclerView","RecipeHolder is binded");
    holder.bindRecipe(recipes.get(position));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return recipes.size();
}

public class RecipeHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    TextView name;
    RatingBar ratingBar;
    public RecipeHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        name= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
        ratingBar=(RatingBar) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);

    }
    public void bindRecipe(Recipe recipe){
        name.setText(recipe.getName());
        ratingBar.setRating((float)recipe.getRate());
    }
}
```

И если поможет Recipe Lab

```
public class RecipeLab {
    private SQLiteDatabase database;

    private static RecipeLab instance;

    public static RecipeLab getInstance(Context context) {
        if (instance ==null){
            instance =new RecipeLab(context);
        }
        return instance;
    }

    private RecipeLab(Context context) {
        database=new RecipesSQLHelper(context.getApplicationContext()).getReadableDatabase();

    }
    public List<Recipe> getRecipes(String table){
       Cursor c= database.query(table,null,null,null,null,null,null);
        RecipeCursorWrapper cursorWrapper=new RecipeCursorWrapper(c);
        List<Recipe> list=new ArrayList<>();
        cursorWrapper.moveToFirst();
        if (cursorWrapper.getColumnCount()==0){
            return list;
        }
        while(!cursorWrapper.isAfterLast()){
            Recipe recipe=cursorWrapper.getRecipe();
            recipe.setTable(table);
            list.add(recipe);
            cursorWrapper.moveToNext();
        }
        cursorWrapper.close();
        return list;
    }
}
```

Надеюсь на помощь

Comment: После закрытия `Navigation drawer`, появляются ли в `List<Recipe> recipes` в адаптере новые данные?

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/553743/177345

Comment: При запуске RecyclerView наполнен  данными после закрытия Navigation Drawer  данными те же.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

как оказалось проблема в Navigation View, он не обрабатывает натиска на items. Я заменил его на другой

```
DrawerBuilder drawerBuilder= new DrawerBuilder()
            .withActivity(this)
            .withActionBarDrawerToggle(true)
            .withRootView(R.id.cont)
            .withHeader(R.layout.navigation_header)
            .withActionBarDrawerToggleAnimated(true)
            .addDrawerItems(getiDrawerItems())
            .withOnDrawerItemClickListener(new Drawer.OnDrawerItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onItemClick(View view, int position, IDrawerItem drawerItem) {
                    Tables[] tables=Tables.values();
                    adapter.refreshData(tables[position-1].getTableName());
                   if (drawer!=null&&drawer.isDrawerOpen()){
                       drawer.closeDrawer();
                   }
                    return true;
                }
            })
            .withToolbar(toolbar);
    drawer =drawerBuilder.build();
```

Answer (score 1):

У меня была та же ситуация. Я вышел из неё так:
В адаптере создал метод который чистит коллекцию с данными и заполняет ее новыми данными. Затем вызывается метод notifyDataSetChanged который обновляет адаптер.

```
public void refreshData(String table){

    //Чистим коллекцию с данными
    recipes.clear();

    //наполняем измененными данными
    recipes=recipeLab.getRecipes(table);

    //передергиваем адаптер
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

А из самой MainActivity в нужный момент вызываем этот метод у адаптера.
В вашем случае нужно эти 2 строки

```
((RecipeAdapter)recyclerView.getAdapter()).setRecipes(table);
        recyclerView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
```

заменить на

```
recyclerView.getAdapter().refreshData(table);
```

Comment: А вообще плохая практика сетить данные в адаптер через метод (setRecipes), так как постоянно нужно следить что бы перед передачей адаптер уже был создан. Данные лучше передавать через параметр конструктора адаптера либо доставать уже в самом адаптере.

Comment: К сожалению, решение не работает.Если при запуске выводится список рыбных блюд, то после нажатия на NavigationView список остается неизменным.Данные те же

Comment: Для того что бы данные изменились их нужно изменить. Проверьте вносятся ли вообще изменения в БД, перед нажатием на NavigationView.

Comment: Данные не должны изменяться в БД. Они оттуда получаются и виносятса в recyclerView .

Comment: Не совсем понятно, что должно измениться при нажатие на  NavigationView?

Comment: В recyclerView должны выводиться новие данние з других таблиц.

Comment: В методе refreshData(String table) после очистки коллекции recipes залейте правильные данные (выборка из БД) и передерните адаптер notifyDataSetChanged(); так как я написал в примере выше. Мне кажется причина в том, что вы обновляете адаптер recyclerView.getAdapter().refreshData(table);  не в том месте или передаете в метод название старой таблицы (table)