# Обновление данных ListView

Tags: android, android-studio

У меня организован `WebSocket`, и при определенном сообщении у меня обновляется ListView..

Код

```
 @Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
    public void onUpdate(Baff[] baffs){
        if(this.baffs==null) {
            // Поступили первые данные создаем baffAdapter и сохраняем его
            this.baffs=baffs;
            baffAdapter = new BaffAdapter(getActivity()
                    , this.baffs, this);
            setListAdapter(baffAdapter);
        }
        else{
            // Обновление данных
            this.baffs=baffs;
            baffAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
```

Обновление данных не происходит, все как было так и остается.

Comment: перед вызовом обновления списка нужно передать в адаптер новые данные (а не просто присвоить их переменной), например как в [этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/553996/177345) в конце

Comment: @pavlofff спасибо